# Getting hierarchy data from self-referencing tables

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, hierarchy

Let's say you have the following table:

```
items(item_id, item_parent)
```

... and it is a self-referencing table - `item_parent` refers to `item_id`.

What SQL query would you use to SELECT all items in the table along with their depth where the depth of an item is the sum of all parents and grand parents of that item.

If the following is the content of the table:

```
item_id     item_parent
----------- -----------
1           0          
2           0            
3           2          
4           2          
5           3
```

... the query should retrieve the following set of objects:

{"item_id":1,"depth":0}
{"item_id":2,"depth":0}
{"item_id":3,"depth":1}
{"item_id":4,"depth":1}
{"item_id":5,"depth":2}

P.S. I'm looking for a MySQL supported approach.

Comment: What database and version? Recursive queries are vendor-specific, if supported at all.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: That is assuming that he is using MS SQL Server.

Comment: True, but Recursive CTE's *are* part of the standard and SQL Server is *not* the only product that supports them.

Comment: Emmanuil:  If you need MySql specific answers, then you should have specified that somewhere.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I apologize about that. I wrongly assumed that the answer would apply to any DBMS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the database is SQL 2005 / 2008 then...

The easiest way to get this is using a CTE (Common Table Expression) that is designed to recurse.

```
 WITH myCTE (Item_id, Depth)
 AS
 (
    Select Item_ID, 0 as Depth From yourTable where Item_Parent=0
    Union ALL
    Select yourTable.Item_ID, Depth + 1 
    From yourTable 
    inner join myCte on yourTable.item_Parent = myCte.Item_Id
 )

 Select Item_id, Depth from myCTE
```

The output is as follows:

```
Item_Id  Depth
    1   0
    2   0
    3   1
    4   1
    5   2
```

From that you can format it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'd love to see a MySQL supported approach.

Comment: Emanuil: it is your responsibility to inform folks of implementation requirements (like MySQL) *before* they try to answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good tech article on the mysql website about hierarchical data in MySql:
[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) - you can find a few detailed solutions with pro and cons there.

Especially the part about "The Nested Set Model" and "Finding the Depth of the Nodes" should be of interest for you.

Comment: In case someone is wondering if Doctrine supports this, there is a nice extension: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a very convenient syntax for retrieving hierarchical data like this:

```
select
    item_id,
    item_parent,
    level as depth
from
    items
connect by
    prior item_id = item_parent
start with
    item_parent not in (select item_id from items)
```

This starts with the root nodes of your trees as those items whose item_parent does not exist in the table as item_id, and selects all children of those nodes, along with their depth in the tree.

Comment: I did not know that Oracle had this. This ia good to know. Wouldn't it be more efficient if parents had a null value in the item_parent column so that we can avoid the "not in" and an extra select

Answer (score 2):

MySQL

- http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html
- http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

EDIT: removed unnecessary information

Comment: Unfortunately http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I need to find a solution for the same task, found some articles, but still didn't choose which way to go...

http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

May be these links might help you. If you find a good solution - please post it here. i'm not allowed to post more then 1 link - i will add some to next posts

Comment: http://www.evolt.org/article/Four_ways_to_work_with_hierarchical_data/17/4047/index.html

Comment: http://www.alandelevie.com/2008/07/12/recursion-less-storage-of-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database/