# SQL Query with "feedback loop"

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I am using MySQL

I have 2 tables:

### Table objects:

```
| id | desc |
| 1  | 'A'  |
| 2  | 'B'  |
| 3  | 'C'  |
| 4  | 'D'  |
| 5  | 'E'  |
```

### Table implies:

```
| id1 | id2 |
| 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 3   |
| 2   | 4   |
| 2   | 5   |
| 3   | 5   |
```

**Table Implies columns id1 and id2 are both foreign keys to table objects id.**

Which means:

object 1 implies object 2 and object 3.

object 2 implies object 4 and object 5

object 3 implies object 5

Therefore, Object 1, implies 2, 3, and 4 and 5 (Since 2 implies 4 and 5)

Is there any way to create a query for this behaviour? My current solution consists on calling recursively from java the query until I don't get any new info:

SQL Query Im calling:

```
SELECT o.id, i.id2 
FROM objects o 
    INNER JOIN implies i ON o.id = i.id1 WHERE id = 1;
```

I first call it with id = 1, then with id IN (2, 3)... etc

The kind of result I want to achieve:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id = 1
```

should return:

```
| id | id2  |
| 1  | 2    |
| 1  | 3    |
| 1  | 4    |
| 1  | 5    |
```

Comment: It looks like your `JOIN` by itself (remove the `WHERE` clause) would do the exact same thing as doing "a loop" going over all `ID` values. Are you maybe looking for a result set for each `ID`?

Comment: Because 1 implies ("is linked to") 2 and 3, and 2 is linked to 4 and 5.  (3 is also linked to 5).  Only the second table is important.

Comment: Add to your questions that `id2` has a related field on 'id1' of implies table. It is a self-referenced table.

Comment: This question has a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199942/getting-hierarchy-data-from-self-referencing-tables

Comment: @Mayday, if you know the maximum number of levels of recursion, you could just INNER JOIN more implies tables, e.g. `...INNER JOIN implies2 i2 ON i.id = i2.id1`

Comment: @Steve Smith I can not know the levels of recursion. Database will grow and the linked objects also, depending on external users

Comment: You'll need a recursive query (which is not available in mysql, IIRC)